# Ajax Contact Form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I've been looking for an ajax (jQuery or any other framework) form that will send three variables in the background and then display some text instead of itself without refreshing the website.

Example:

http://net.tutsplus.com/demos/contactform/

Example above comes with tutorial, but unfortunately the PHP back-end for it doesn't work so I'm searching for something else.

Do You have something in mind? Or any tips for jQuery beginner how to build it from the ground up?

If requests like this are forbidden here then I want to ask how to send variables using this script:

```
    $.ajax({  
  type: "POST",  
  url: "bin/process.php",  
  data: dataString,  
  success: function() {  
    $('#contact_form').html("<div id='message'></div>");  
    $('#message').html("<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>")  
    .append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>")  
    .hide()  
    .fadeIn(1500, function() {  
      $('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='images/check.png' />");  
    });  
  }  
});  
return false;
```

To back-end? I had a long fight with own my bin/process.php file and nothing seems to work ("success" part of jQuery script never occurs).

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you post `bin/process.php`?

Comment: Ideally you should hide `#message` at the start to avoid bad animation and change the `#contact_form`'s html on callback from the fade-in.

Comment: I've tried to modify the original file from this pack: http://net.tutsplus.com/demos/contactform/demo.zip - but doesn't seem to work. Then tried with my own file, it looks like that: http://jsfiddle.net/d2Z3R/, sorry for $Body = $message in my script, just cut a few lines of body to show the core of my script. @Fred, thank you, but the biggest concern at the moment is backend not working at all.

Comment: I think you need to add an `echo '';` or `return`. I'm not 100% sure, so please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

"success" should fire if bin/process.php exists and outputs something. You can write process.php the way you would normally write a form submission handler (i.e. with or without AJAX) because the data will be available in `$_POST`.

Then, if your front-end page has a contact_form element (`<div id="contact_form">`) you should see the result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an `echo '(something)';` to your PHP and it should work. You should change your JS to the following for better animation:

```
$.ajax({  
  type: "POST",  
  url: "bin/process.php",  
  data: dataString,  
  success: function() {  
    $('#message').hide(data)
    .html("<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>")  
    .append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>")    
    .fadeIn(1500, function() {  
      $('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='images/check.png' />");
      $('#contact_form').html("<div id='message'></div>");  
    });  
  }  
});  
return false;
```

To pass variables, you need to set `dataString` to either `'key1=bob&key2=bob2'` (string) or a dictionary - `{key1:'bob', key2:'bob2'}`. For more info, see the [jQuery ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

You can also add error handling by changing the `echo` message and then adding an if .. else statement in the success function. You could also use JSON, but it's overkill for this.